# \section* doesn't work with \renewcommand{\section}

Tags: sectioning, amsmath

I'd like to modify the `\section` command and I'd like to sometimes use `\section*`, but this doesn't work with amsmath package.

The code below works fine without it, but I often need it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  

\makeatletter  
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%  
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%  
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%  
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%  
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}%  
    }  
\makeatother  

\begin{document}  

\section{Section 1}  

\subsection*{Introduction}  
\lipsum[2]  

\section{subsection 1}  
\lipsum[2]  

\end{document}
```

with amsmath,when I use `\subsection*{my subsec title}`, it prints the subsec number and then a star where the "my subsec title" should be. And this title doesn't show up.

Thanks for any clue to sort it out

Comment: you are missing `%` from two of the lines

Comment: Welcome. It would be easeier if you just tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

The code posted is missing a couple of `%` but in most uses that won't affect the output (unless you load `amsmath` which changes the behaviour of white space around `\@ifnextchar`).

By default it does define the `*` form to give unnumbered subsections.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}



\makeatletter
\subsection*{aaa}
aaa

\renewcommand{\subsection}{
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    }

\subsection*{bbb}
bbb

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}%
    }

\subsection*{bbb}
bbb

\end{document}
```

As always if you have code that isn't working, post a *complete* document as here, that shows the problem.

If you add

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Then you will see instead

[image]

Showing the issue is as mentioned originally your missing `%` the version in the question doesn't work, but the following redefinition works as intended.

Comment: Ok, I should have posted a code extract to show the problem, that would have help me know where it really is.

Comment: The problem is with the amsmath package. The code below works fine without it, not if it's loaded :
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsection}{
 \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection*{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\section{subsection 1}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}

Comment: @FabC, please  add it to the question, as you see code in comments doesn't really woprk

Comment: @FabC see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle it actually works with the % that were missing, the problem wasn't amsmath. strange that it occurs only when it's loaded, but I won't question further, it works, and that's enough for me

Comment: @FabC no it is amsmath, it changes the definition so it no longer skips white space so your spurious spaces make it `\section\space *` which does not work with the amsmath version. they are wrong always but the behaviour is more noticable with amsmath loaded.